# Good examples/templates/best practices API documentation

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, api, specifications

Im creating the front end for a web service, and another company the back end. I need a good, simple and easily understandable way of making a document of API calls that we can collaborate on and edit together without confusing one another.

are there any good specs/examples etc of project API documentation so this doesnt get in a huge mess with many re-writes?

Comment: The entire Python library is a good example of project API documentation.  It seems like you would simply start here.  http://docs.python.org/library/.  What's wrong with using what you already have as an example?

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, I assume the backend will be written in Python. The tags you use indicate this, but you don't say so explicitly.

Comment: @MortenSiebuhr yes, this is true, but i didnt think it was that important as I have no knowledge of Python as a language and still need to contribute to how the API should function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My choice for documentation: [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/).

Others:

- [epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/)
- [pylit](http://pylit.berlios.de/)

But Sphinx is quite awesome.

Comment: looks interesting, but too heavy on the python side for my liking as I have no influence on the python and need to make my own changes and suggestions too.

Comment: @shortstick; You don't need to do any python coding. Just install Sphinx and you only need to write markup. No python at all.

Comment: Sphinx seems to be working pretty well, so ill give you the hit for that one. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For small APIs I´ve began to use Google Docs. Its collaboration features are awesome and you can see a list of all changes made on this document.